# Is it safe to remove Release.key file?

Tags: wine

I just installed wine by adding the their repository as described in their [official page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) , everything went fine but now the file "Release.key" appears in my home folder, is it safe to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes now that you have imported the key you can delete it from your home directory.

The key is now stored by apt (apt-key).

> apt-key is used to manage the list of keys used by apt to authenticate
>   packages. Packages which have been authenticated using these keys will
>   be considered trusted.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-key.8.html for details.